# How do I append to an NSMutableDictionary inside of an NSArray?

Tags: ios, swift

The collection is being fetched from a JSON file via:

```
if let collection = dictionary!.objectForKey("collection") as? NSMutableArray
```

The following does not work:

```
for item in collection as! [NSMutableDictionary]
{
    // mutating method sent to immutable object
    item["row"] = 1
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "collection":
    [
        {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 0
        },
        {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 1
        },
        {
            "row": 2,
            "col": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes!? the object is immutable, why would you want to change the value? extract the needed information, maybe change some of the extracted data and then move on

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. `collection ` is the extraction, but I cannot modify the `NSMutableDictionary` inside it.

Comment: if you get an exception that tells you that an object is immutable, then the object is immutable. the computer is right, you are wrong.

Comment: I get the same error when doing a `.mutableCopy()`. I think `as! [NSMutableDictionary]` is seen "as immutable array". How do I write that line to be mutable?

Comment: why are using "let", let makes the thing immutable, user var instead,

Comment: Same issue with var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting JSON object should be constructed with mutable containers and you need to cast the collection to be mutable as well.

```
let json = "{\"collection\":[{\"row\": 1,\"col\": 0},{\"row\": 1,\"col\": 1},{\"row\": 2,\"col\": 0}]}"
if let
    jsonData = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false),
    dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSMutableDictionary {

    if let collection = dictionary["collection"] as? NSMutableArray {
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: collection.count, by: 1) {
            (collection[i] as! NSMutableDictionary)["row"] = 1
        }

    }

}
```

You may also want to consider a JSON library like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Out of curiosity, is it possible to do this without making the JSON object mutable? Like using `array.mutableCopy()` somehow.

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta are you trying to mutate an immutable object? that's not gonna work, regardless of what you want or how you think the system works. If you want to mutate a container, it needs to be mutable. Pretty much by definition.

Comment: No, I want to extract the immutable container, add some properties to it, then assign it to a transformable.

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta - See my edit. SwiftyJSON takes care of lots of the casting gymnastics you need to do when working with JSON directly.